# How to get EstimatedRows values from SQL Server execution plan nodes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, azure-sql-database, xml

When I execute the following code in an Azure SQL Database (v12) or SQL Server 2016 instance, I get values in the **EstimatedRowsRead** column, but not in the **EstimatedRows** column, and I'm not seeing why. Any ideas?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
,PlanHandles AS (
    SELECT  plan_handle
            ,total_elapsed_time =   SUM(total_elapsed_time)
            ,execution_count    =   SUM(execution_count)
      FROM  sys.dm_exec_query_stats
     GROUP  BY plan_handle
)
,Plans AS (
    SELECT  ph.plan_handle, qp.query_plan, ph.total_elapsed_time, ph.execution_count
      FROM  PlanHandles ph
            OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(ph.plan_handle) qp
)
SELECT  p.total_elapsed_time
        ,p.execution_count
        ,p.plan_handle
        ,p.query_plan
        ,NodeId                 =   s.i.value(N'@NodeId', N'INT') 
        ,EstimatedRowsRead      =   s.i.value(N'(@EstimatedRowsRead)[1]', N'FLOAT')
        ,EstimatedRows          =   s.i.value(N'(@EstimatedRows)[1]', N'FLOAT')
  FROM  Plans p
        CROSS APPLY query_plan.nodes('/ShowPlanXML/BatchSequence/Batch/Statements/*') q(n)
        CROSS APPLY n.nodes('.//RelOp[IndexScan and IndexScan/Object[@Schema!="[sys]"]]') s(i)
 WHERE  s.i.value(N'(@EstimatedRowsRead)[1]', N'FLOAT') > 1.0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is a small typo but I agree that Estimatedrows would seem like the way to go.

In the execution plan's XML it is called `Estimaterows` instead of the expected `EstimatedRows`.

An example:

[image]

```
EstimateRows="12"
```

This should work:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
,PlanHandles AS (
    SELECT  plan_handle
            ,total_elapsed_time =   SUM(total_elapsed_time)
            ,execution_count    =   SUM(execution_count)
      FROM  sys.dm_exec_query_stats
     GROUP  BY plan_handle
)
,Plans AS (
    SELECT  ph.plan_handle, qp.query_plan, ph.total_elapsed_time, ph.execution_count
      FROM  PlanHandles ph
            OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(ph.plan_handle) qp
)
SELECT  p.total_elapsed_time
        ,p.execution_count
        ,p.plan_handle
        ,p.query_plan
        ,NodeId                 =   s.i.value(N'@NodeId', N'INT') 
        ,EstimatedRowsRead      =   s.i.value(N'(@EstimatedRowsRead)[1]', N'FLOAT')
        ,EstimatedRows          =   s.i.value(N'(@EstimateRows)[1]', N'FLOAT')
  FROM  Plans p
        CROSS APPLY query_plan.nodes('/ShowPlanXML/BatchSequence/Batch/Statements/*') q(n)
        CROSS APPLY n.nodes('.//RelOp[IndexScan and IndexScan/Object[@Schema!="[sys]"]]') s(i)
 WHERE  s.i.value(N'(@EstimatedRowsRead)[1]', N'FLOAT') > 1.0;
```

**Result example**

```
NodeId  EstimatedRowsRead   EstimatedRows
3         530                1
4         1,93078            1
9         12                 12
8         12                 12
```

Comment: <sigh> It does seem like Microsoft should have been more consistent in their naming. Thanks for noticing what I clearly did not.

Comment: @mark I agree! No problem, it is often those little differences that get you :)